# if i learn something using a pirated software, is using the knowledge haram?

Tags: halal-haram, piracy

I was stressed on this for weeks. If I'm learning something using a pirated software, I'll use that knowledge someday. Maybe I'll make money with the knowledge. Will that money become haram?

Comment: It's effectively the same as this question, with "knowledge" instead of "work": [After switching from pirated software to free software will my work still be haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/13168/17163).

Comment: This is a duplicate of [On earning gotten from forbidden knowledge](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37707/17163)

Answer (score -1):

That act of using Pirated Software would be a case of Theft. And yes, your earned money could also go towards Haram or at least Makroh. But if you are earning money then its better to pay the price of software and buy it now. 
May AL-MIGHTY ALLAH would forgive all our sins. Ameen.